# Django static file serving in conflict with React Router

Tags: python, django, reactjs

My website uses Django as backend and React.js as frontend. Frontend are compiled with react-scripts build so that Django backend can serve it as static files. When running the web app with 'python manage.py runserver', I am faced with the following issue:

The website serve just find for the root url 'http:localhost:8000/'. However, if I want to go to a suburl 'http://localhost:8000/team/'. **Backend fails to load all the static files**. Log from backend looks like the following:

```
[20/Jan/2020 20:23:43] "GET /team/static/media/%E8%82%96%E8%8A%B7%E7%8E%A5.93cb5dfd.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3137
[20/Jan/2020 20:23:43] "GET /team/static/media/%E6%9D%8E%E4%B8%80%E5%87%A1.e74fa446.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3137
[20/Jan/2020 20:23:43] "GET /team/static/media/%E9%83%87%E5%AE%87%E6%AC%A3.af12f28b.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3137
[20/Jan/2020 20:23:43] "GET /team/static/media/%E9%AB%98%E8%AF%97%E5%85%83.ff52ce19.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3137
[20/Jan/2020 20:23:43] "GET /team/static/media/%E8%83%A1%E6%B7%87%E5%AA%9B.88f0c659.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3137
[20/Jan/2020 20:23:43] "GET /team/static/media/%E7%8E%8B%E9%80%B8%E5%87%A1.4fe694ba.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3137
[20/Jan/2020 20:23:43] "GET /team/static/media/%E8%B4%BA%E9%80%B8%E6%83%9F.e77dedac.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3137
```

Django automatically append '/team/' in front of '/static/' so all the files originally located in '/static/' could not be found and rendered. This is very tricky and I can not find any solutions online.

Here is my urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.static import serve

from .views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^.*$', index),
]
```

where

```
index = never_cache(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
```

My settings.py looks like the following:

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build', 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build', 'media')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build', 'static')
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to get rid of that '/team/' prefix that Django is automatically appending?

Comment: How are you getting the static files, did you make sure to add '/' before in order to get the static file from the base url localhost:8000. Also I have a pre-configured fully running Django project serving React with Webpack if you want, its clean and easy to use.

Comment: If I directly enter 'localhost:8000', static file is loaded from '/static/js/main.6e43aa73.chunk.js'. If I enter 'localhost:8000/team/'. static file will be loaded from '/team/static/xxx', which is not desired. Is that what you are asking? It would be nice if you can show me the link to your preconfigured project. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/Occy88/django_project/   hey I have added a great tutorial with everything you might need, please let me know what you think and if it solved your issues, it is a fully setup package you can follow the guide and it will give you a great starting point with django, react, webpack, deployment and more... The guide is a quick read and will save you a tonne of time in the future. also feel free to contribute if you find any defficiecies

Answer (score 2):

This has been a headache for me as well.. I managed to fix it by adding the domain of my website to `homepage` in `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "homepage": "https://example.com/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.1.5",
    "@sindresorhus/slugify": "^1.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
...
```

I reckon this is not really ideal, especially if you have multiple domains, but it is the easiest way to make it work. `.` or `./.` didn't work for me.

The difference was very subtle. After running a `build` with `homepage: "."`, my `asset-manifest` was looking like this:

```
{
  "files": {
    "main.css": "/static/css/main.f45be922.chunk.css",
    "main.js": "/static/js/main.a84f15c1.chunk.js",
    "main.js.map": "/static/js/main.a84f15c1.chunk.js.map",
    "runtime-main.js": "/static/js/runtime-main.f8f17c43.js",
...
```

After running it with `"homepage": "https://example.com"`, it looked like this:

```
{
  "files": {
    "main.css": "./static/css/main.f45be922.chunk.css",
    "main.js": "./static/js/main.a84f15c1.chunk.js",
    "main.js.map": "./static/js/main.a84f15c1.chunk.js.map",
    "runtime-main.js": "./static/js/runtime-main.f8f17c43.js",
...
```

That `.` at the beginning of each file made the difference and my program was able to finally find the statics.

If anyone knows a cleaner way to fix this, please share it!

Comment: trust me if i could vote two times for your answer, i would do it, thank you ,that helped me

Answer (score 0):

instead of trying to change the way you serve static files to avoid conflicts with react statics, you could just name Django's static files route as some thing other than `static` ,name it `staticfiles` for example,i.e `STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'`.

you don't need to change the folder name as well so `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` would work as expected, and later try to redirect `/staticfiles` route with nginx to your static files folder.