# Directing to nested URL with react router from server

Tags: reactjs, django, react-router-dom

I am building an app with `django3.2` and `React 17` using `react-router-dom 6`.

My react app is served at
`https://www.example.com/`

And if I navigate within the app to `https://www.example.com/auth/signup` I get the form, however, if I input the url directly into the browser I am taken to a blank page.

In my django.urls, I have a catch all that should send the path down to my react app, and in local development it works great.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    re_path(r'^(?:.*)/?$', homepage),
]
```

PROBLEM: In production I am taken to a blank page.

I suspect it has to do with relative paths in production. I've followed these questions:

[Django static file serving in conflict with React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59830522/django-static-file-serving-in-conflict-with-react-router/66950806#66950806)

[React router not loading dynamic url in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68503208/react-router-not-loading-dynamic-url-in-production)

And so far have tried:

1. Adding `"homepage": "https://www.example.com/"` to my `package.json`.
2. Adding `<base href="/" />` to `index.html`
3. Adding `"homepage": "."` to `package.json`

But so far nothing has worked, and I need this feature, particularly for email verification. Happy to clarify anything or share front end code.

Comment: What sort of server environment is hosting/serving your app? Does anything in the [create-react-app deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) docs help?

Comment: I'm on python anywhere. I fixed it by serving the ```index.html``` file built by react directly, but this is a temp fix. I was parsing out the info from ```index.html``` and serving my react app on another html file - really not sure why there would be a difference. And thanks for the links.